# Ctrl+R acting like holding space bar

Tags: 18.04, usb, kernel, input-devices

Whenever I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, it acts like I'm holding down the keyboard (i.e. typing tons of spaces). If I press the space bar, it stops.

Things I've tried:

- Different programs: Happens in Chrome, gedit, terminal, and PyCharm at least
- Different keyboard (continued to happen; cannot be a keyboard issue)
- Different USB Port (continued to happen; cannot be a port connection issue)
- Behavior also happens when using an on-screen keyboard
- **Booting into a Live CD: Does not happen; therefore I know it has to be some configuration somewhere in Ubuntu.**
- Upgrading Ubuntu: This behavior has existed at least from 14.04 and I'm currently on 18.04 (will upgrade to 20.04 soon)
- Keyboard profile: Set to correct keyboard layout
- Keyboard input method: Confirmed set to iBus
- Language setting: Confirmed to be set correctly
- Watched the relevant `/dev` input and confirmed there's no signals being received from hardware while this is happening.

I'm comfortable digging through kernel logs and whatever is needed to debug this, but I don't really know where to go from here.

Comment: Is there a reason you are using 14.04 and not 16.04?

Comment: Don't particularly want to go through the hassle of upgrading. I chose the LTS so I don't have to upgrade all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Check that your keyboard profile is set correctly for your country. Check to make sure that you haven't set up a keyboard shortcut that uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. Check this setting...

[image]

Comment: How exactly do I check the keyboard profile? I checked the other things and they're all correct.

Comment: The Language Support, Region & Language, and Keyboard system settings panels. If you don't find an incorrect setting there, I don't have any more ideas for you. Although you could try booting to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and see if the problem occurs there.